# Scroll Issue after setting height to iframe using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, iframe

I am setting height dynamically to `iframe` using `jquery`. It is working fine but issue is that if user `clicks` on link to view more data which is below of `DataList` then it sets height perfectly to `iframe` but it scrolls to top itself. I want to keep `Scroll position` where it is at a time of `Click` on `LinkButton`. I am using c# `LinkButton` but it doesnt matter here. Whole page is inside `iFrame` so I am just setting `iframe` height based on `document` height. and so calling `function` on `pageLoad()` of `jquery` as per code.

**My Code :**

```
        function adjustHeight() {
            var iframe = jquery(window.top.document).find("#frameContent");
            iframe.height(0 +'px');

            var height = jquery(document).height() + 30;

            iframe.height(height +'px');
        }

        function pageLoad() {
            adjustHeight();
        }
```

How to do it ? Everything is in `c#`. `DataList` and `LinkButton` are inside `UpdatePanel` And I am just setting height using `jquery`.
HTML Code : [DataList HTML with View More](http://pastebin.com/L3fqtVUr)

Comment: Maybe you have a piece of code such as `.scrollTop()` somewhere else ?

Comment: Which datalist? Which linkbutton? Not enough context at all, make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Brewal, no. I am not using `.scrollTop()` anywhere.

Comment: I answered below on the assumption that you have a # link or something causing your page to jump up (or the page inside your iframe). A fiddle would help greatly.

Comment: What is href `href` of the link ? Do you  handle it with a `onclick` event ?

Comment: @Brewal, It is `C# LinkButton`. I am using it to display more records. It is same as we find View more data on any website.

Comment: ... Give the resulting html. We can't do magic

Comment: Does the button have a unique id, class? I still believe (as I answered below) that you need to prevent the default action of the button (link) after clicking it.

Comment: Updated post shows an image, NO html that we can explore. This does not help. Please, paste the resulting HTML code.

Comment: I still don't see any html. I doesn't matter for jQuery that the app is in C#, PHP python ruby or whatever... jQuery is working on the DOM. That means we **do need** html.

Comment: @SimonDowdles, nw check.

Comment: This is ASP... You should tag it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries, I got solution.

It was causing issue just because I am setting height 0 to frame before setting new height.
Simply, I removed below line and it worked. :)
`iframe.height(0 +'px');`

Answer (score 0):

From what I hear, I am assuming that the link the user is clicking is an anchor link, or a # link, correct? That would result in the page jumping to the top. What you can do, is return false inside of your click function / event:

Example:

`$("a.someLink").bind("click", function(e){
   // Your logic here...
   // The below prevents the native behavior of the link occurring...
   e.preventDefault();
   e.returnValue = false;
   return false;
})`

**UPDATE**

Try remove the inline javascript function from your button (link) and rather implement it with jQuery, adding the return false etc in. So your button code now looks like this:

`<a href="#" class="viewmore" id="lnkbtnViewMore">View More</a>`

And jQuery like this:

`$("#lnkbtnViewMore").bind("click", function(e){
   __doPostBack('lnkbtnViewMore','');
   e.preventDefault();
   e.returnValue = false;
   return false;
})`

That should do the trick...

Comment: I don't know why this has been dv

Comment: Why the down vote?? It states clearly in the OP's question "...clicks on link..."

Comment: I am not using any `inline javascript`. `LinkButton` gets more data by using `code behind ClickEvent` .

Comment: Yes, you are using inline Javscript. This javascript right here, is "INLINE" with your `<a>` element: `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkbtnViewMore','')"...`

Comment: Did you try my suggestion above? If I look at your code in the fiddle, I see no reason for it not to work. The default behavior of a link without an external URL and without preventing the default behavior IS to send the page (window) back to the top. Thus, moving the function into a jQuery bound event function and returning false should do the trick.

Comment: And, if you insist on writing your javascript inline like that, at the very least remove it from the `href` attribute and rather insert it into the `onclick` attribute, eg: `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkbtnViewMore','')">...</a>`